# Consumindo Json com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, vraptor

Estou tentando acessar um `EndPoint` através do AngularJS.

Esse é meu Service:

```
angular.module('empresa-view')
    .factory('empresaService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource($SERVICES_CONTEXT + 'empresa/:params', {}, {
            update: {
                method: "PUT"
            },

            lista: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {params: 'list'},
                isArray: true

            }

        });

    }]);
```

Quando rodo a aplicação da o seguinte erro:

> GET  XHR  http://localhost:8080/ExemploVraptor/empresa [HTTP/1.1 405
>   Method Not Allowed 5 ms] erro[object Object] main.js:12:21 Requisição
>   cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin
>   Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em
>   http://localhost:8080/ExemploVraptor/empresa. (Motivo: o cabeçalho
>   CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

Porém se troco o `empresa/:params` por `empresa/list'` funciona e consigo exibir pegar os dados. Porque o `params` não está funcionando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Creio que a concepção da fatctory de serviços do AngularJS esteja equivocada.

Aqui vai a documentação oficial https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Para fazer isso como você você teria que passar o :params na chamada do service, por exmeplo.

```
meuServico.$lista({params: list});
```

Na declaração do próprio serviço ficaria

```
angular.module('empresa-view')
    .factory('empresaService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource($SERVICES_CONTEXT + 'empresa/:params', 
        {params: list}, 
        {
            update: {
                method: "PUT"
            },

            lista: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true

            }

        });

    }]);
```

Mas não vejo motivo para fazer isso.

Quando você declara os defaultParams dentro do próprio service ele passa via URI, ficando por exemplo http://localhost:8080/ExemploVraptor/empresa?params=list.

Por isso que ele alega a violação de cross-origin.

> Editado

Você poderia fazer o seguinte (se achar melhor)

```
angular.module('empresa-view')
        .factory('empresaService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
            return $resource($SERVICES_CONTEXT + 'empresa/:params', 
            {params: @parametros}, 
            {
                update: {
                    method: "PUT"
                },

                lista: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true

                }

            });

        }]);
```

Então quando você instanciar esse serviço, pode passar diretamente pela propriedade do objecto. Por exemplo

```
var meuServico = new empresaService();

meuServico.parametros = "list";

meuServico.$lista();
```

> Editado, para responder melhor a pergunta sobre o query

Por padrão todos os serviços angular tem esses métodos

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Ao utilizar a factory é como se você ganhasse esses invokers de brinde. Então mesmo sem declarar o query, ele sabe que existe um método query que está ligado ao ser serviço do tipo GET que espera um ARRAY de resposta e vai ser solicitado a URL declarada.

E como tudo no angular funciona como injeção de dependência, ao você passar o serviço para o seu controller, você já pode acessa-lo diretamente se a necessidade de usar o **new** você apenas usa o **new** para atribuir os aspectos do seu serviço a outro objecto (prototipagem).

Comment: Eu também não entendo muito, estou acompanhando um tutorial: https://pedrohosilva.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/aplicacao-web-com-vraptor-4-pt10-3/ Por isso estou tentando fazer dessa forma

Comment: @Techies veja a edição que eu fiz no post, espero que te ajude mais um pouco.

Comment: Entendi sim, outra dúvida. no meu controlle faço isso: ` empresaService.query(fucntion...` aqui é onde faço a pesquisa certo? Mas como isso está ligado ao meu service?

Comment: @Techies veja a segunda edição do post. Se responde sua dúvida.

Comment: Obrigado, @Erick. Consegui resolver e obrigado pela explicação adicional.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que seu servidor necessita de acesso CORS para poder executar saída JSON, coloque isso no header da sua saída JSON:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

E para toda a sua aplicação, defina o **useXDomain**:

```
angular.module('empresa-view')
    .factory('empresaService', ['$resource','$httpProvider', function ($resource,$httpProvider) {
          $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
          delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

     var params = {'list':'list','param1':'valor_param1'} 
        return $resource($SERVICES_CONTEXT + 'empresa', params, {
            update: {
                method: "PUT"
            },
            lista: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,

            }

        });

    }]);
```

Aqui tem alguns exemplos: **http://notes.3kbo.com/cors**

Comment: Eu já tenho um CORS. Esse é o endpoint completo: `http://localhost:8080/ExemploVraptor/empresa/list` o :params deveria receber `list` porém não recebe. Se eu coloco o `list` direto no lugar de :params funciona

Comment: Pelo detalhe do erro na sua resposta, está claro que o erro é de permissão do servidor, se não funcionar, provavelmente seja alguma configuração do apache que não está configurado para uso de CORS: no `.htaccess`, faça isso: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: então seria melhor eu passar o list direto ao invés de passar ela como parâmetro?

Comment: ficaria asism: `return $resource($SERVICES_CONTEXT + 'empresa/list', {}, {`

Comment: Se você já está passando o parâmetro na coleção do json, não precisa passar ele na url. Olha na resposta um exemplo.